# React Router not rendering the right page when links are clicked, only works when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a simple login system and log out for a testing blog that I'm trying to learn more about React. The links and redirections were working fine initially, but when I finished the Private Routes, the links started to render the Not Found page. It renders the Not Found page every time I click on any link, or it makes a redirection. And to render the right page, I need to refresh the page or type it manually.

Does anyone have any idea what's happening here that could help me to understand this problem better? I tried a lot of stuff, but nothing worked. I believe it's some problem in the App.js in the  or the AuthContext.js that is a React Context that deals with the authentication part, but I still don't know what it is.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
    function CustomRoute({ isPrivate, ...rest }) {
        const { loading, authenticated } = useContext(Context);

        if (loading) {
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
        }

        if (isPrivate && !authenticated) {
            return <Redirect to='/' />;
        } else {
            return <Route {...rest} />;
        }
    }

    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
                        <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                        <CustomRoute isPrivate exact path='/posts' component={Posts} />
                        <CustomRoute
                            isPrivate
                            exact
                            path='/post-content'
                            component={PostContent}
                        />
                        <CustomRoute isPrivate exact path='/new' component={NewPost} />
                        <CustomRoute isPrivate exact path='/edit' component={EditPost} />
                        <Route component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </Fragment>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**AuthContext.js**

```
const Context = createContext();

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (token) {
            axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(token)}`;
            setAuthenticated(true);
        }

        setLoading(false);
    }, []);

    async function handleLogin(event, values) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/auth/login';
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        };

        await axios
            .post(url, values, config)
            .then((resp) => {
                const token = resp.data.token;

                localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));
                axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
                setAuthenticated(true);
                history.push('/posts');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error) {
                    setAuthenticated(false);
                    localStorage.removeItem('token');
                    axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = undefined;
                    history.push('/');
                }
            });
    }

    function handleLogout(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        setAuthenticated(false);
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = undefined;
        history.push('/');
    }

    return (
        <Context.Provider
            value={{ authenticated, handleLogin, handleLogout, loading }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}

export { Context, AuthProvider };
```

Any ideas what could be causing it?
Thanks

Comment: make a way in which whatever you receive as a success signal to `document.body.innerHTML=whateverSuccessfulReponseMeh`

Comment: You'll have better luck getting an answer to this type of question if you make a code sandbox (e.g. https://codesandbox.io/) with a working example.